# Outliers identification using tso function: run-time & error

Tags: r, outliers

I am forecasting daily (log transformed) sales with about 2500 observations. I tested stationary. I used the `tso` function for the outliers identification, with the inclusion of regressors such as *DayOfWeek*, *MonthYear*, *DayOfMonth*, *WeekOfMonth*, *WeekOfYear*, *Public Holidays*. However, for some datasets I get the following message:

```
Error in arima(y, order = fit$arma[c(1, 6, 2)], seasonal = list(order = fit$arma[c(3, : non-stationary seasonal AR part from CSS
```

or:

```
Error in arima(x = c(3.29950729870049, 3.63367040605144, 59.6705024612701, : non-stationary seasonal AR part from CSS
```

I tried several options in the `ars.method` & `tsmethod` and nothing worked. I also looked to change from conditional sum of squares (CSS) to maximum Likelihood (method="ML"), but I could not find such an option for the `tso` function. I would appreciate your feedback on how to solve it.

---

I fixed it by adding the (p,d,q)(P,D,Q) parameters from a previous `arima` fit in the `tsmethod` as follows:

```
fit <- tso(df.ts,types=c("AO","LS","TC","IO",'SLS'), 
              xreg=cbind(r1.matrix,r2.matrix,r3.matrix,r4.matrix),
            discard.method="bottom-up", tsmethod="arima", 
            args.tsmethod=list(order=c(0,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,2), period=7)))
```

Yet, for some datasets worked simply with `tsmethod="auto.arima"`. I appreciate some feedback on the matter. In addition, I would greatly appreciate some feedback on why it takes around one hour to run the code with `tso` function (in the best scenario) or simply it never ends running. I am running the code in a virtual workstation with the following characteristics: Intel(R)Xeon CPU @ 2.3 GHz with 32.0 GB RAM and SSD 500 GB.

Comment: I have no idea what 'TSO' refers to in this scenario. It does not seem too be what the tag is for - Time Sharing Option.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the (p,d,q)(P,D,Q) parameters from a previous `arima` fit in the `tsmethod` as follows:

```
fit <- tso(df.ts,types=c("AO","LS","TC","IO",'SLS'), 
              xreg=cbind(r1.matrix,r2.matrix,r3.matrix,r4.matrix),
            discard.method="bottom-up", tsmethod="arima", 
            args.tsmethod=list(order=c(0,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,2), period=7)))
```

Yet, with some datasets worked simply with `tsmethod="auto.arima"`. I appreciate some feedback on the matter. In addition, I would greatly appreciate some feedback on why it takes between half to one hour to run the code with  `tso` function. I am running the code in a virtual workstation with the following characteristics: Intel(R)Xeon CPU @ 2.3 GHz with 32.0 GB RAM and SSD 500 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems regarding the error message and the run-time.

outliers <- tso(ts(y,start=c(2007,1), freq=12),xreg=ts(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, dummy1),start=c(2007,1), freq=12), types = c("AO", "LS", "TC"), tsmethod = "arima", args.tsmethod = list(order=c(1,0,0)))
Error message: Error in arima(x = c(-0.335877994658354, -0.325693106566002, -0.327243422084559,  : 
  non-stationary AR part from CSS

My solution was not run all types of outliers at the same time. For example:
outliers_ao_ls <- tso(ts(y,start=c(2007,1), freq=12),xreg=ts(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, dummy1),start=c(2007,1), freq=12), types = c("AO", "LS"), tsmethod = "arima", args.tsmethod = list(order=c(1,0,0)))

outliers_tc <- tso(ts(y,start=c(2007,1), freq=12),xreg=ts(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, dummy1),start=c(2007,1), freq=12), types = "TC", tsmethod = "arima", args.tsmethod = list(order=c(1,0,0)))

I hope it helps. By running the tests separately, it is working well. It is not a justification for your problem but I also did not find any explanation about how to change the estimation method to "ML".